# Nativescript - TypeError: Cannot read property 'LayoutParams' of undefined

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

tns 2.5.0-2016-11-16-7142
npm 3.10.9

[This](http://%20https://github.com/agrawal-mohit/fundoo/tree/debug) is a NS-ng project with very minimal code. On running, the cli throws this -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {org.nativescript.fundoo/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException:  Calling js method onCreateView failed
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'LayoutParams' of undefined File:
>   "/data/data/org.nativescript.fundoo/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view.js,
>   line: 507, column: 68
>
> StackTrace:   Frame:
>   function:'ViewStyler.setNativeLayoutParamsProperty',
>   file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.fundoo/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view.js',
>   line: 507, column: 69     Frame:
>   function:'StylePropertyChangedHandler.applyProperty',
>   file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.fundoo/files/app/tns_modules/ui/styling/style.js',
>   line: 1326, column: 14    Frame: function:'Style._applyStyleProperty',
>   file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.fundoo/files/app/tns_modules/ui/styling/style.js',
>   line: 1086, column: 25    Frame: function:'Style._applyProperty',
>   file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.fundoo/files/app/tns_modules/ui/styling/style.js',
>   line: 1049, column: 14    Frame: function:'Style._onP

This supposedly had to do with the module versions but I have it updated :

```
"tns-core-modules": "^2.5.0-2016-11-16-4793",
"tns-core-modules-widgets": "^2.5.0-2016-11-10-154"
```